# Visual FoxPro Multi Table Form

Tags: database, foxpro

I just started working with FoxPro at school and I have a few problems when I try to create a form that needs to add data to muliple tables (no designer).

I am using the APPEND command but this seems to add data only to the main table.

Any suggestions for a solution are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly select the work area (alias or table) before doing an append.  For example, in your "CLICK" event you would do something like...

```
SELECT FirstTableName
append blank
replace FieldW with "something",;
        FieldX with 1.23,;
        FieldY with SomeVariable,;
        FieldZ with Thisform.SomeTextbox.Value

SELECT SecondTableOrAlias
append blank
replace FieldA with Thisform.AnotherTextbox.Value,;
        FieldB with Thisform.SomeCheckBox.Value

SELECT ThirdTableOrAlias
append blank
replace ...
```

If the tables are NOT already opened from the form's DataEnvironment, you might want to ensure they are open first by doing the following BEFORE the above Append/Replace

```
if not used( "FirstTableName" )
   select 0
   use FirstTableName
ENDIF 

if not used( "SecondTableOrAlias")
   select 0
   use SecondTableOrAlias
endif
```

etc...

Additionally, VFP DOES support SQL too, so you could do

```
insert into FirstTableName ;
   ( FieldW,;
     FieldX,;
     FieldY,;
     FieldZ ;
   );
   values ;
   ( "something",;
     1.23,;
     SomeVariable,;
     Thisform.SomeTextbox.Value ;
   )
```

And to query data out via SQL-Select

```
select * from FirstTableName ;
   where FieldW = "something" ;
   into cursor C_SomeTempResultSet READWRITE
```